# Upgrading windows 7 to windows 10 default application settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I have a bunch of Windows 7 Machines that need to be upgraded to Windows 10.  I have found that after running the upgrade I can't seem to set the default apps.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this.  Does the core OS stay Windows 7?  Not sure how to archive this.

Comment: For a bunch of machines, make a .reg file with the app settings: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/registry-location-of-default-windows-10-apps/62fc4cf6-3c94-44a7-9efc-8ff7aaaa851c

Comment: Also, take one Windows 10 machine and learn what the default apps are. Many defaults are fine as Windows 10 defines them.

Comment: "Does the core OS stay Windows 7?" - If a Windows 7 machine is upgraded to Windows 10, then Windows 7 no longer exists on the machine, only Windows 10.  It is not clear, what you mean by "core OS", you should edit your question to clarify this point.  Please do not submit a comment in response to to my question.

Answer (score 0):

The most you can do while upgrading to Windows 10 is to set during the
upgrade the option of "Keep personal files and apps",
then check whatever still works after the upgrade.

Windows 10 is very different from Windows 7, so prepare for surprises:

- Old devices might stop working and you will need to search for Windows 10 drivers
- Some applications will not fully work and you will need to search for Windows 10
  versions
- Default apps might cross over fully, partially or not at all, so prepare for
  for manually reseting them
- In Windows 10, programs can no longer make direct changes to default associations.
  Instead, any such attempt will rather open the Settings App for manual change.

Conclusion: You will have to take your chances with the upgrade.

Prepare also for an unsuccessful upgrade, so create a disk image backup
and a boot CD/USB that can put it back,
just in case the computer becomes unbootable after a botched upgrade.
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
is quite good for that.

Comment: I have found that some defaults such as Outlook as the default mail program get moved but not all.  I would like to not manually set them as this in in an enterprise environment and I can't set the default apps for every computer and every user that uses that computer.